# Scrollr problems on Wordpress for mobile (where to put the scrollr-body id tag)

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I finally had my popup footer looking okay on my laptop and now it doesn't work on my mobile devices. I understand from the Scrollr readme file that I need to add an id tag somewhere. I'm not sure where to place the tag relative to the standard Wordpress templates.

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/blob/master/README.md

I initially put the tag in my footer.php file because that's where I placed the rest of my scrollr action script. Didn't work out so well. My footer appears and disappears yet the rest of the page remains static. Any thoughts?

my site: http://www.essaypress.org
pass: reddit

TIA!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the parallax is happening, but here is some info as to why skrollr isn't working on mobile, and the best place to put #skrollr-body:

Smartphone browsers limit the the javaScript processing when scroll is initiated, excessively so on iProducts.

Skrollr "fakes" scrolling by using a css transition to simulate. anything labeled with #skrollr-body will have this effect.

**Where to put it:**

#skrollr-body will not work on anything that has a position of "fixed", because that conflicts with fundamental CSS3 transition properties.

In my most recent project, I had a 100% div width scrolling homepage, with content above the parallax that needed to scroll, and content below, with the middle div set to a fixed positioning.

**I did this:**

I wrapped #skrollr-body around all of my content, and used javaScript to reorder the DOM so that everything else would scroll. I then margined the lower div 9000px from the top element which allowed my animation to play on the scroll before it reached the lower content.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, Justin, but I ended up giving up. It was too difficult to determine where exactly to place the #skrollr-body tag within my mess of interconnected Wordpress php files. I tried footer.php, header.php, content.php, etc.. and nothing seemed to work for me.